# eforms: Why are "nlc=," in front of the button?

Tags: forms, acrotex, button

```
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\pushButton[onclick={this.submitForm({cURL: "mailto:test <test@google.com>", }), this.exportAsText();},
            \CA{Send}\AC{Me}\RC{Reset}\A{/S/ResetForm}]{SendButton}{50bp}{15bp}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

However I get the characters `nlc=,` in front of the button. Is this an error from the package or am I the error?

[image: Button]

Comment: `\begin{Form}` but `\end{From}`... You will have to correct the typo in the second command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` is hyperref syntax (`\PushButton`) and not eforms (`\pushButton`}.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{eforms}
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\PushButton[onclick={this.submitForm({cURL: "mailto:test <test@google.com>", }), this.exportAsText();}]{Send}

\bigskip
\pushButton[\AA{\AAMouseDown{\JS{
             this.submitForm({cURL: "mailto:test <test@google.com>", }), this.exportAsText();}}}
             \CA{Send}\AC{Me}\RC{Reset}\A{/S/ResetForm}
             ]%
           {SendButton}{50bp}{15bp}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```